# Is customer conversion higher with fixed or selective currency payment options?

Tags: payments, conversions, subscription

I want to offer a monthly paid-subscription plan so that users on my website can access more features.

Most sites I visit only accept payment in USD. Would customer conversion by higher if the payment was only in USD, or if people were allowed to pay in their preferred currency (Euro, GBP, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing people to pay with their preferred currency *should* offer you higher conversion rates as anything that makes the user's experience easier typically increases conversion rates. However, offering too many options can have the opposite effect as users can feel overwhelmed and/or be confused by their options and abandon the payment process altogether. A good compromise would be to offer a few of the most common currencies so your users can choose a preferred currency without having too many to choose from.